# Do optimization techniques map to sampling techniques?

Tags: sampling, optimization

From any generic sampling algorithm, one can derive an optimization algorithm.

Indeed, to maximize an arbitrary function $f: \textbf{x} \rightarrow f(\textbf{x})$, it suffices to draw samples from $g \sim e^{f/T}$. For $T$ small enough, these samples will fall near the global maximum (or local maxima in practice) of the function $f$.

By "sampling" I mean, drawing a pseudo-random sample from a distribution given a log-likelihood function known up to a constant. For instance, MCMC sampling, Gibbs sampling, Beam Sampling, etc. By "optimization" I mean the attempt to find parameters maximizing the value of a given function.

---

Is the reverse possible?
Given a heuristic to find the maximum of a function or a combinatorial expression, can we extract an efficient sampling procedure?

HMC for instance seems to take advantage of gradient information. Can we construct a sampling procedure that takes advantage of a BFGS-like approximation of the Hessian?
(edit: apparently yes: http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4464-quasi-newton-methods-for-markov-chain-monte-carlo.pdf)
 We can use MCTS in combinatorial problems, can we translate that into a sampling procedure?

Context:  a difficulty in sampling is often that most of the mass of the probability distribution lies within a very small region. There are interesting techniques to find such regions, but they do not directly translate into unbiased sampling procedures.

---

Edit: I now have a lingering feeling that the answer to that question is somewhat equivalent to the equality of complexity classes #P and NP, making the answer a likely "no". It does explain why every sampling technique yields an optimization technique but not vice versa.

Comment: Although I think I have a conventional understanding of most of the words in this question, I'm unsure what it's getting after. Could you state a little more precisely what you mean by "sampling" and what exactly would be "optimized"? You seem to assume implicitly that your readers have in mind a particular setting in which a "distribution" (or family thereof?) is involved and in which a particular objective is assumed, but one can only guess at what you really intend when you make such broad statements as those appearing in the last paragraph.

Comment: By "sampling" I mean, drawing a pseudo-random sample from a distribution given a log-likelihood function known up to a constant. For instance, MCMC sampling, Gibbs sampling, Beam Sampling, etc.

By "optimization" I mean the attempt to find parameters maximizing the value of a given function. For example, gradient descent, the simplex algorithm, simulated annealing are optimization techniques.

Comment: There's a natural mapping between Simulated annealing and MCMC sampling. There's a less direct mapping between HMC and gradient descent (if you squint). My question is whether this can be made more systematic. A difficulty in sampling is often that most of the mass of the probability distribution lies within a very small region. There are interesting techniques to find this region, but they do not directly translate into unbiased sampling procedures.

Comment: Please edit your question to include these clarifications. That is crucial because your (somewhat specialized) use of the word "sampling," although appropriate in your context, differs from what many readers may understand. Also, your explanation of "optimization," although correct, does not appear to be helpful in making its meaning sufficiently precise here: characterizing what the "given function" is and how it might be related to "sampling" would be useful additions.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: I cannot post comments yet so I am going to post a solution here with my comment and maybe someone can move it up above. My question is whether or not "From any generic sampling algorithm, one can derive an optimization algorithm" is a true statement or not? It does not seem intuitive to me at all that that is true. Can you provide a reasoning behind that or a source?

Comment: Yes, as explained, draw from $e^{-f/T}$ for $T$ sufficiently small.

Comment: Do you have a source/citation for this?

Comment: Yes, certainly.  I appreciate your efforts: this is an intriguing idea.  Based on the answers you are getting, I'm not sure your question is being understood, though.  If you continue to get replies that don't seem to address your question, please look at them closely and consider whether there might be any additional changes you could make to clarify it.

Comment: It's trivial if $f$ is continuous and its domain is compact?

Comment: "Trivial" mathematically, yes: but whether it is in the least *practicable* is another matter entirely!  But I take it--please feel free to correct me if this is wrong--that you are not concerned in this thread about practicability; this is more of an open-ended query about whether there may be any conceptually fruitful way to view sampling and optimization as two aspects of the same thing.

Comment: I guess it's trivial for some but not for all :(

Comment: @whuber I suspect that finding a general connection between the two, abstract as it may be, will lead to fruitful implementations.

Comment: @Dan if you need help visualizing it, imagine that you exaggerate the function $f$ by stretching it, making the maxima into very high peaks. If you draw a random sample, it will fall near those maxima because they are, by construction, extremely likely.

Comment: @Dan http://pbrd.co/1tjfXiM first image is some function $f$, second is the distribution $e^{-f}$, third shows $e^{-f/T}$ for a few values of $T$, last shows $e^{-f/T}$ for a very small value of $T$. Do you see why drawing from this last distribution would help find the minimum of $f$?

Comment: I see now.  Awesome!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @ArthurB. the link pbrd.co/1tjfXiM is dead. Could you provide the full reference? And if possible a new working link.

Comment: Sorry, no :(
I think it's some image I drew at the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a link, it's the Gumbel-Max trick !

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~cmaddis/pubs/astar.pdf

Answer (score 4):

One connection has been brought up by Max Welling and friends in these two papers:

- [Bayesian Learning via Stochastic Gradient Langevin Dynamics](http://www.columbia.edu/~jwp2128/Teaching/E9801/papers/WellingTeh2011.pdf)
- [Bayesian Posterior Sampling via Stochastic Gradient Fisher Scoring](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.6380.pdf).

The gist is that the "learning", ie. optimisation of a model smoothly transitions into sampling from the posterior.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to find the CDF of the heuristic. Then from monte carlo theory we know that for $ U \sim unif[0,1]$ that $F^{-1}(U) \sim F$ where F is the cdf of the distribution you are after. If you cannot find the cdf exactly, you could use a simple acceptemce-rejection based heuristic.